# What is better to return single value from stored procedure to .Net: OUTPUT parameter or ExecuteScalar?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create a stored procedure that needs to return a count of some records. I'm using .Net to read the result.

I can use an `OUTPUT` parameter to return the value *or* I could do a `select count(*)` in the stored procedure and use a [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) to read it.

What is better and why?

Comment: Or you could use a `RETURN` parameter, as you asked about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587814/what-is-better-to-return-a-single-value-in-tsql-stored-procedure-a-return-or-an

Comment: You need to create a stored procedure but you're asking if you should write a stored procedure or not. You should do what you're supposed to do.

Comment: @Oded well... the answer actually is that a `RETURN` should not be used for anything else than error signaling.

Comment: My point is that @gbn seems to have answered this question in his answer as well.

Comment: @Oded the statement about the scalar might be incorrect (http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2007/05/01/3049.aspx) and was besides the point of that question that was limited to `output` vs. `return`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this MSDN article: [Performance Comparison: Data Access Techniques](https://web.archive.org/web/20121109191353/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978388)

The article shows in the performance test for `GetOrderStatus` that the performance between OUTPUT parameter and ExecuteScaler is the same for retreiving a **single value**, but ExecuteScalar requires less code.

Here are some other interesting thoughts about not going for the OUTPUT parameter: 
[What's wrong with output parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434402/whats-wrong-with-output-parameters). I like the thought of `Output params break the fundamental idea of a function` in that post.

Comment: I agree for the C# domain, but the SQL domain is a bit different, because in many cases we like to optimize the way things are transported and to limit overhead.

Comment: +1 For the performance testing link. [Interesting Graph](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC161808.gif)

Comment: Old article, but maybe even more relevant now. With client, network and server specs are vastly better, the choice of technique probably doesn't matter. A stored proc isn't a function though as I commented there (I answered too)

Comment: Using scalars is all very well until you need to get the result in another T-SQL script, then it becomes a bit of a pain especially if your SP also returns a value.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely - OUTPUT parameter is the fastest and rightest way

Comment: Do you have some documentation to back this statement up?

Comment: Yes, ExecuteScalar creates TDS, which is relatively heavier operation than passing OUTPUT parameter back (its for word "fastest"). RETURN is recommended for returning only error states of execution (this is for word "rightest"). If you need the proof, i'll find one

Comment: @OlegDok - I've heard that `OUTPUT` parameters are more light weight as well but am not sure how much benefit if any there actually is in practice. Would be interesting to see the structure of a TDS packet for both.

Comment: One more thing - parameter can be strongly typed - I think that it is also a benefit.

Comment: As far as I know - the Tabular Data Stream for OUTPUT parameters is not created at all. But the actual benefit is tiny - this matters on massive calls of very lightweight procedures

Comment: @OlegDok - TDS is just the name of the protocol for communicating with the client. How else would they get passed the value?

Comment: One more benefit of OUTPUT - is scalability - you can return more than 1 value instead of ExecuteScalar

Comment: @Martin Smith - thats why I mentioned AFAIK. So I was wrong here

Comment: @Martin Smith but in case of ExecuteScalar it still have to parse a recordset

Answer (score 0):

To add a thought - `ExecuteScalar` will return status code if SP does not mention otherwise. It seems to be good practice to keep that around.